# Problem in installing Ubuntu 12.10 on Samsung Notebook.

Tags: installation, 12.10, reboot

Everyone, I'm a new comer to Ubuntu.
Recently, I downloaded the Ubuntu Desktop 12.10 (64 bit) ISO file. After verifying that the file is not damaged or corrupted, I install it on a 4 GB Sandisk pen drive using Universal USB installer. After booting Ubuntu from pen drive, it automatically reboots every time when I boot it from the pen drive.
It dont give me any chance to install it.

I don't know why it is happening? Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! At what exact stage after the attempt to boot does it unexpectedly reboot? Do you see the initial "Try Ubuntu" "Install Ubuntu" screen? Do you see any Ubuntu logo appearing? Do you have any indication that booting from this flash drive is working at all? (e.g. try other bootable image, check BIOS boot order, etc.) Please **edit** your question to include this information.

Comment: This sentence "After booting Ubuntu from pen drive, it automatically reboots every time when I boot it from the pen drive." is difficult to understand. Could you please rewrite it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're talking about. I'm having a problem installing it as well... I installed it from windows (I'm using a flash drive as well) And it told me to restart. I restarted and was prompted with a screen that says something along the lines of "file missing in c:/ubuntu/winboot/...". It tells me to hit emter to go to the next screen where it prompts me with an OS selection screen. If I choose Ubuntu, it restarts again, and if I choose Windows 8 then it continues as normal.

Comment: I noticed you mentioned c:/ubuntu/winboot... were you using the WUBI installer?

Answer (score 0):

If it is one of the newer Samsung notebooks (I assume you have Windows 8 preinstalled), it comes with UEFI enabled. And AFAIK, disabling UEFI to enable CMS emulation makes it impossible to boot from a pendrive, at least that is what I experienced.

My advice is to disable UEFI and try to install Ubuntu from a DVD. For learning how to disable UEFI, you can check the tutorial on this link: [Disable UEFI on Windows 8](http://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-access-uefi-bios-setup-in-windows-8/)

There is also another alternative that I have not had the chance to test more than once yet. Without going through the hassle of disabling UEFI from Windows 8 interface, you can try to press F2 "as soon as" you power up the laptop. You have to do it fast, and it may take you to BIOS setup.